# White Space Above and below navbar in Laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I have a navbar, but I don't know where the white space can display above and below my navbar, but when I try without using Laravel, the white space is gone.

I have try use css
`* { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }`

but the result is same

here my Navbar paste.ofcode.org/xWBgAJUmWt5h7dYdALNnjC
and my css paste.ofcode.org/nNwTafvyzECeRgWSjUhrT9

[With Laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFQqs.png)

[without Laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mya7D.png)

Comment: you are using the bootstrap in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Two causes:

1. The browser has a native 8px margin on the body, so start with:

   `html, body{ margin: 0; }`
2. `header .top-bar .social` is poking out. Make it:

   `header .top-bar .social { margin: 0; }`

And the problems are gone.

You can then delete the

```
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with Height:

.navbar {
height : 20px ; //required height
}